# iPad: How to close a UIPopoverController by pressing its own "Done" button

Tags: uipopovercontroller

My popover has its own "done" button, I want to dismiss my popover by touching this option but still can't figure out how, this is a capture of the app

[image: screen capture]

The code of creation (inside rootview controller named VisitVC)

```
- (IBAction)showStartEndEvent:(id)sender {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewSceneStartEndEvent" sender:self];

    else
    {
        //iPad Popover Section
        if (!startEndEventPopover || !startEndEventPopover.popoverVisible)
        {
            StartEndEventVC *controller     = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartEndEventVC"];

            controller.FecInicioDateSE      = self.fecInicioDateV;
            controller.fecFinDateSE         = self.fecFinDateV;

            navController               = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
            navController.toolbarHidden = FALSE;

            startEndEventPopover        = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

            [startEndEventPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(400, [sender convertPoint:[sender bounds].origin toView:self.view].y, 300, 400) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            }
        else{
            [startEndEventPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            startEndEventPopover = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

now the "done" button code inside popover controller (StartEndEventVC)

```
- (IBAction)saveChanges:(id)sender {

    if (fechaInValida) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notificación" message:@"La fecha de inicio debe ser anterior a la fecha de finalización" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    [self comparaFechaInicio];


    [self.startDateLabel    removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text"];
    [self.endDateLabel      removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text"];

    [CurrentParentViewController setFecFinDateV:self.fecFinDateSE];
    [CurrentParentViewController setFecInicioDateV:self.fecInicioDateSE];


    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    else{
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
    }
}
```

the code key for dismissing the popover is on the block:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else{
    **[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];**
}
```

but don't know how, any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dismiss a popover you have to send `dismissPopoverAnimated:` to your popover controller. To accomplish that, you should keep a reference to your popover, and then from the view controller you are presenting in your popover controller inform the view controller you are presenting your popover from about the button press, and at this point you call `dismissPopoverAnimated:`. You can use delegation or a block to inform about the button press.

Answer (score 1):

I did it!!! with delegate, all I have to do is to implement a delegate to my popover's class (startEndEvent.h)

```
@class StartEndEventVC;

@protocol StartEndEventVCDelegate

@optional -(void)startEndEventsVC:(StartEndEventVC *)sender;

@end

@interface StartEndEventVC : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic)           id <StartEndEventVCDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

inside my save data method I implemented the delegate like so...

```
- (IBAction)saveChanges:(id)sender {

    if (fechaInValida) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notificación" message:@"La fecha de inicio debe ser anterior a la fecha de finalización" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    [self comparaFechaInicio];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"]){
        [self.startDateLabel    removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text"];
        [self.endDateLabel      removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text"];

        [CurrentParentViewController setFecFinDateV:self.fecFinDateSE];
        [CurrentParentViewController setFecInicioDateV:self.fecInicioDateSE];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    else{
        [self.delegate startEndEventsVC:self];
    }
}
```

and finally on my rootViewController's class (VisitVC.m) I adopted my custom StartEndEventVCDelegate

```
@interface VisitVC ()<StartEndEventVCDelegate>
...
@end
```

I set my popover's delegate and implement the popover's delegate method

```
- (IBAction)showStartEndEvent:(id)sender {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewSceneStartEndEvent" sender:self];

    else
    {
        //iPad Popover Section
        if (!startEndEventPopover || !startEndEventPopover.popoverVisible)
        {
            StartEndEventVC *controller     = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartEndEventVC"];

            controller.FecInicioDateSE      = self.fecInicioDateV;
            controller.fecFinDateSE         = self.fecFinDateV;

            controller.delegate = self;

            navController               = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
            navController.toolbarHidden = FALSE;

            startEndEventPopover        = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

            [startEndEventPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(400, [sender convertPoint:[sender bounds].origin toView:self.view].y, 300, 400) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
            }
        else{
            [startEndEventPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            startEndEventPopover = nil;
        }
    }
}

-(void)startEndEventsVC:(StartEndEventVC *)sender{    
    [startEndEventPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

there it is... if you have a smaller solution is welcome but it works just fine :)